# Store and perform action on universal data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to optimize my application. I have a universal database, like country, the country has many states, the state has districts and so on. Right now I have the same information in RDBMS. What if I want to take it in my Java application? I was thinking about MAP, but after a little progress I am stuck. what would be a better data structure to store this information?

Comment: you need to be more specific

Comment: Alright, what can be a better data structure if we want to store data of a country, Say for example India, India has 29 states and each state has districts?hope its better now.

Comment: this seems more like a data modeling question.  you should retag accordingly